# Find max element in array OpenMP and PPL versions run much slower than serial code

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp, ppl

I'm trying to implement two versions of a function that would find the max element in the array of floats. However, my parallel functions appeared to run much slower than the serial code.

With array of 4194304 (2048 * 2048) floats, I get the following numbers (in microseconds):

- serial code: 9433
- PPL code: 24184 (*more than two times slower*)
- OpenMP code: 862093 (*almost **100** times slower*)

Here's the code:

PPL:

```
float find_largest_element_in_matrix_PPL(float* m, size_t dims)
{
    float max_element;
    int row, col;
    concurrency::combinable<float> locals([] { return (float)INT_MIN; });
    concurrency::parallel_for(size_t(0), dims * dims, [&locals](int curr)
    {
        float &localMax = locals.local();
        localMax = max<float>(localMax, curr);
    });

    max_element = locals.combine([](float left, float right) { return max<float>(left, right); });
    return max_element;
}
```

OpenMP:

```
float find_largest_element_in_matrix_OMP(float* m, unsigned const int dims)
{
    float max_value = 0.0;
    int i, row, col, index;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(max_value, index)
    for (i = 0; i < dims * dims; ++i)
    {
#pragma omp critical
        if (m[i] > max_value)
        {
            max_value = m[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    //row = index / dims;
    //col = index % dims;
    return max_value;
}
```

---

1. What's making the code run so slowly? Am I missing something?
2. Could you help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know PPL, but your OMP code is not parallel at all. Get rid of the critical section in the loop and reduce the result when the loop is done.

Comment: @BaummitAugen getting rid of critical section indeed made the code run 5 times faster than the serial variant! But what do you mean by 'reduce the result when the loop is done'?

Comment: If you are using libstdc++, you can also try `std::max_element` with the [parallel mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html). That will handle the OMP stuff for you.

Comment: *"But what do you mean by 'reduce the result when the loop is done'?"* Let every core find its own maximum and combine them when all cores are done. [First hit on google](http://www.techdarting.com/2013/06/openmp-min-max-reduction-code.html), did not test myself. In general, you need to try pretty hard to avoid shared data if you want fast multithreaded code.

Comment: unfortunately, the version of OpenMP I use doesn't allow `max` in `reduction` directive

Comment: You can easily do this by hand, analog to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20421200/3002139) answer.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978222/openmp-c-algorithms-for-min-max-median-average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as [Baum mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002139/baum-mit-augen) noticed, the problem with OpenMP was that I had a critical section and the code didn't actually run in parallel, but synchronously.
Removing critical section did the trick.

As for PPL, I've found out that it does a lot more preparations (creating threads and stuff) than OpenMP does, hence the slowdown.

---

## Update

So, here's the correct variant to find max element with OpenMP (the critical section is still needed but inside the `if` block):

```
float find_largest_element_in_matrix_OMP(float* m, unsigned const int dims)
{
    float max_value = 0.0;
    int i, row, col, index;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < dims * dims; ++i)
    {
        if (m[i] > max_value)
        {
            #pragma omp critical
            max_value = m[i];
        }
    }
    return max_value;
}
```

PS: not tested.